# BGI error, How to Resolve it?

Tags: c, turbo-c, bgi

I want to run a C program that draws a circle. The program is compiling with no error and it is running. After getting the values like radius from the user, I get the error like this :

`BGI error: Graphics not initialized ( use "initgraph")`

Even though in my source code I have added this line :

```
int gmode,gdrive=DETECT;
initgraph(&gdrive,&gmode,"c\\tc\\bgi");
```

Still I'm getting error.

I'm using Windows and I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C:\\tc\\bgi you mean this path right?

Comment: @JesusRamos Oh I'm a novice in C graphics so i'm not sure. So whats the correct path?

Comment: In windows your path starts with Drive:\\path\\to\\folder if you want a literal string of it

Comment: Did you just copy that without fixing it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316337/c-program-line-not-drawing/3316893#3316893

Comment: @HansPassant : Yes to be honest. Since I'm a novice thought it was a correct.

Comment: @HansPassant Wow that's quite a find.

Comment: @Jesus, credit to the OP for upvoting it today.  Not for reading it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your path in `initgraph` is wrong. Use `"c:\\tc\bgi"` instead.

Comment: Backslashes must be escaped in literals.

Comment: @Alex Yeah I forgot the markup on here messes up the backslashes (you have to use 4 to get 2) thanks

Comment: otherwise copy BGI folder content into BIN folder

Answer (score 4):

If you get this error message when you run your graphics program: `BGI Error: Graphics not initialized (use 'initgraph')`

Just you need to copy the \tc\bgi\EGAVGA.BGI file to your local folder where you are running the application.

Comment: the other solutions didn't work but this worked for me running turbo c++ in dosbox on max os high sierra

Answer (score 2):

**Try this (it worked for me) :**

The BGI folder is usually in the following path,

*C:\TurboC++\disk\TurboC3\BGI*

So the code you need to put in your program is as follows,

```
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TurboC3\\BGI");
```

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered from that problem.

Simply put this line:

```
initgraph(&gdrive,&gmode, "c:\tc\bgi");
```

here `c:\tc\bgi` is important.

**MOST IMPORTANT:**

In `tc.exe` (which you are using) at top are some menus like file, edit, options:

- Go options>application
- select overlay (By Default it is "standard" but you must select "overlay" option), then click on ok.
- now you run your graphics progaram.

**NOTE:** in the output, if it gives an error about **bgi**, ignore it, just give the input for the program if it is required and it will give you the graphics output. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Could be multiple reasons:

- wrong path to the bgi file (I see the colon is missing)
- unsupported graphics mode (don't expect DOS graphics apps to work under Vista and up)

Answer (score 0):

if by including "C:\tc\bgi" still the error persists , try this:
goto file-> change directory..
change it to bgi.. but this has to be done every time u open the turboc