# BGI Error in opening C++ program with DOSBox

Tags: c++, dosbox, bgi

I have a program in c++ that uses graphic.h
I want to open it with dos-box but when I try I get this error from dos-box:

```
BGI Error: Graphics not initialized (use 'initgraph')
```

I have used initgraph in my program in this way:

```
gd=DETECT;
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
```

Comment: You may be using it wrong. Check this page: http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/

Comment: Show us your code. At the least a relevant portion of it. Then we might be able to help.

Comment: gd=DETECT initgraph(&gd,&gm,"") the program used to run correctly with this codes in windows 7 and dos-box

Comment: More details are needed. It seems this is Borland specific. Some code would also be useful to determine what happens.

Comment: Wrong path to BGI probably in the code. That said, don't use Turbo and their outdated compilers and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check the initgraph(), it should be something like

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\TC\BGI");
```

If it doesnot work try giving an extra slash like:

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
```

If again it doesnot not work check the environmental variables also.

You may refer to existing post in [BGI error, How to Resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605942/bgi-error-how-to-resolve-it)

Comment: and those backslashes should most probably be escaped.

Comment: I can't find the file BGI in the folder that contains tc.exe

Comment: @Feri: That is the main problem, you will find the drivers in BGI folder, please make the config correct

Comment: I think they are in the folder that i have turbo c.

Comment: @Feri: Can you pls give more details? Here the initgraph is defined in the the BGIfolder only and you can also trying copying the \tc\bgi\EGAVGA.BGI file to your local folder where you are running the application

Comment: There is not a BGI folder but i have .bgi files in the local folder and i use "" as the third parameter for initgraph

Comment: @Feri: Can you try copying the \tc\bgi\EGAVGA.BGI file to your local folder wfrom here you are running the application

Comment: As I said I have this file in the folder i run the application

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run my old college graphics project in Turbo C++.

```
int gd=DETECT,gm;

 initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");

 if(graphresult()!=grOk)
 {
  closegraph();
  cout<<"Error Initializing graphics engine!!"<<endl;
  getch();
  return -1;
 }
```

I used Macbook Pro early 2015 model with Dosbox installed alongwith Dapplegrey.
http://www.classics-for-x.info/csx/dapplegrey/index.htm

**Screenshots:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv0ON.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/deQiG.jpg