# BGI error when running graphics program from CD

Tags: c++, bgi

I want to run an `.exe` file that I have created from Turbo Cpp in Windows XP.

The program itself is an animation built with Cpp.

The `.exe` file opens fine in Windows XP, but not when it's opened from a CD. The error I get is `"missing BGI"`.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Sounds like the BGI DLL is either not on the CD or not in the path.

Comment: There is some graphics driver named `egavga` or something like that. Please ensure that your program is refering to that file properly.
And refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605942/bgi-error-how-to-resolve-it